# Performance tuning for searching

Tags: java, performance, data-structures

I am fairly new to DS and Algorithms and recently at a job interview I was asked a question on performance tuning along with code. We have a Data Structure which contains multi-billion entries and we need to search a particular word in that data structure. So which Java feature/library can we use to do the searching in the quickest time possible ?

On the spot I could not think of exact answer so I wrote that:

1. We can store the values in a map and search words in the map (but got stuck how to decide key-value pair in the map).

How can I understand the exact answer to this question and what can be the optimal solution(s) ?

Comment: I think your answer is reasonable.  A map has constant lookup time, so having a very large number of entries should not phase this performance.  If you lookup a key and can't find anything, then it isn't in the map.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Please don't post bad answers as comments. (Multiple billion entries will likely not fit into memory)

Comment: @meriton even I got stuck while thinking of this solution (Multiple billion keys entries will likely not fit into memory) and how to decide what will be the value for these keys.

Comment: @meriton I guess I overlooked the size of the data being stored.  But for data sets not having such a memory requirement, a map seems reasonable to me.  Also, try to avoid calling other people's work "bad."

Comment: You could dedicate some non-volatile memory and have it act as conventional random access. Then just apply a standard Hash Table (or similar O(1) search algorithm). While this would come with a time cost, having to read from the non-volatile state, it should be negligible.

Comment: From the question, it sounds like memory isn't an issue since the data structure is already populated.

Comment: Did the interviewer say (or did you ask) anything regarding whether memory constraints are important or whether you can assume, for the sake of discussion, that memory isn't an issue? Was anything said about whether the chosen DS can be assumed to be fully populated? Are there details that you might be omitting on the thought that they may not be relevant? If you can provide the actual question, as stated by the interviewer, and any other follow up details/questions that clarified things, that could make it easier to provide helpful answers.

Comment: @ray .. It was actually in the written part of the interview (the first round). So nothing of that sought was ever discussed and nothing was mentioned in the question as well. Plus I had to code for this on paper.

Comment: @Zachary You said it best: *"assuming ..."*; in interview settings, it's best *not* to assume things. Instead, you should ask. However, you brought a good question/point for OP. Did the interviewer say, or did OP ask, about the alphabet/character set in question?

Comment: But in the feedback I came to know that this question was the reason for my rejection

Comment: What did the feedback state regarding this question?

Comment: @ray Fair point. The assumption was drawn from the phrase "search words", implying English word which would limit it further.

Comment: @JacobG. There was no feedback as such. When I asked for the rejection reason they told because I could not answer the performance tuning question correctly I am rejected.

Comment: Did you press for more information? Perhaps what they were looking for was someone who knew what to ask. From what I can see, there are several outstanding questions that would need to be addressed before an optimal algorithm could be selected/designed.

Comment: @Zachary No. I was probably disheartened. Didn't think of pressing more. Yeah but now I can see that this question in a way was not complete then.

Comment: @mr.cool All a learning experience. Better luck next time

Comment: @mr.cool The post talks about a "data structure" that appears to be populated, and that you need to search on it. What data structure was that? They can't seriously expect you to state which algorithm to use for searching an unknown data structure, so it looks like you they may've been expecting you to ask follow-up questions.

Comment: Please, always remember to come back and up-vote helpful answers and accept the one that you found most helpful overall. This is how we say "thank you" around here :)

Comment: Sure @ray My Bad :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading the question and getting clarification in the comments, I think what has become apparent to me is that: **you needed to ask follow-up questions**.

I'll try to break it down and provide comments that I hope will be helpful, because I also know what it's like to be "in the moment" and how nerves can stab you in the back when you least need them to.

> We have a Data Structure which contains multi-billion entries and we need to search a particular word in that data structure.

I think a good follow-up question here would've been:

**Q:** What *specific* data structure is being used to contain all this data?

I would press until they give me an actual name and explain why it is not possible to name a Java algorithm/library. For all you know, the data structure could've been `String[]`, a `Set<String>`, or even a fancy name for a file on disk (if they're trying to throw you off). They could've also clarified and said the DS was not relevant and that you could pick whichever DS *you* thought was best.

The wording also *implies* that they implemented the structure and that it's already populated in a system with, presumably, enough memory to hold all of it. Asking to *confirm* that this is *really* the case could've given you helpful information.

For example: *"Based on the wording, it seems this mystery data structure is already implemented and fully populated in memory in a system with enough memory to hold it. Can you confirm my understanding here is correct? If not, could you clarify further?"*

Given the suggested wording, and the fact that we don't have additional clarifications to go from, I will *assume*, for the purposes of this answer, that my suppositions are indeed correct.

Note that ***if*** you had been asked to *design the data structure* to hold all of this info, you would've had to ask very different questions, take memory constraints into account, and perhaps even ask about character sets/encodings (e.g. ASCII vs multi-byte Unicode).

Also, if you had been asked to *design the search algorithm*, then knowing the DS is a pre-requisite, and not knowing this could've made the task impossible. For example, the binary search algorithm implementation will look very different if you're working on an array vs a binary search tree, even though both would offer *O(lg n)* time complexity.

> So which java feature/library can we use to do the searching in the quickest time possible?

Consistent with the 1st part, this question only asks what pre-existing/built-in Java code you would choose to perform the search for you. The "quickest time possible" here should make you think about solutions that are in *O(1)*, i.e. are constant time. However, the data structure may open/close doors for you.

Some search algorithms in Java work on generics and others work on other types like arrays. Some algorithms work on `Map`s while others work on `List`s, `Set`s, and so on. The follow-up question from the first part could've helped in answering this question.

That said, even if you knew the DS, but couldn't think of a specific method name or such at the time, I also think it should be considered reasonable to mention the interface or at least a relevant package and say that further details can be checked on the the Java documentation if you're pressed for more specificity, given *that's* what it's there for in the first place.

> We can store the values in a map and search words in the map (but got stuck how to decide key-value pair in the map).

Given the wording, my interpretation of their question was *not* "which data structure would you use?", but rather, "which pre-existing search algorithm would you choose?". It seems to me like it was *them* who needed to answer the question regarding DS.

That said, if you had indeed been asked "which data structure would you use?", then a `Map` would've still worked against you, since you didn't really need to *map* a key to a value. You only needed to *store* a value (i.e. the words). Therefore, a `Set`, specifically a `HashSet`, would've been a better candidate, since it also avoids duplicates and should consume less memory in the process because it stores singular values, rather than key/value pairs.

Of course, that's still under the assumption(s) I made earlier. If memory constraints are said to be an issue, then scaling horizontally to multiple servers and so on would've likely been necessary.

> How can I understand the exact answer to this question and what can be the optimal solution(s)?

It is *probably* the case that they wanted to see if you would follow up with questions, given the lack of information they gave you.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple data structures that allow for efficient searching, assuming that memory requirements aren't an issue and the data structure is already populated.

Regarding time complexity, `Set#contains` and `Map#containsKey` are both `O(1)`, assuming that the hash function isn't expensive and that there aren't many collisions.

Because the data structure stores words (assuming you're referring to `String`s), then it could also be relatively efficient to use a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) (radix tree, prefix tree, etc.), which would allow you to search by character (which I believe would be `O(log n)`).  If the hash function is expensive or there are many collisions, this could be a good alternative!

The answer that you gave to the interviewer should suffice since hashing is an effective searching method, even for billions of entries.

Comment: Yeah even I thought so, but he rejected me and main reason was this question. So I thought of asking it here and then understanding the same.

Comment: Did they give any further reasoning to why your answer was rejected?  If collisions were the problem, then a trie was probably what they were looking for.

Comment: @mr.cool Please edit your OP to mention the reasoning that was given to you as their justification for rejecting your answer to this question, if any. If none was given, please note that as well. That might help point others in the right direction.

Comment: @ray no reason was given that is the problem. They just told me that I did not qualify because I could not answer the performance tuning question. taht

Comment: While hashing is an effective search method, `Set` and `Map` keep the entire data in the java heap, which is not sufficiently scalable to hold multiple billion entries.

Comment: @meriton Of course, hence why I made the assumption that memory usage isn't an issue at the top of the post.  We've determined that the question is flawed though, so I don't expect any answer to be viable.  However, all of the answers here are good for someone who finds this question in a few years.

Comment: Yes, but you still say "The answer you gave should be sufficient". Was it? Obviously the interviewer disagreed, and perhaps we now know why.

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention whether the entries are words or documents (multiple words). In both cases a [search index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_indexing) could be suitable.

Search indexes extract words from the billion document entries and manage a map of these words to the documents they are used in. Frameworks like Lucene (e.g. as part of SOLR or ElasticSearch) manage memory and persistence for you.

If it were only multiple of thousands of entries, a simple HashMap would be sufficient because there is no need for memory management then. If all of the billion entries are single words, a database could be a slightly better choice.

Comment: Yes, he did mention it. *"We have a Data Structure which contains multi-billion entries and **we need to search a particular word** in that data structure"*

Comment: This does not answer my question! It is pretty clear that he wants to search words. One can search a particular word in a set of words or in a set of documents. And the latter is more common.

Comment: Your statement was: *"You did not mention whether the entries are words or documents"*. What I get from that is that you don't know if OP's being asked to search for *words* or for *documents* (i.e. that the entries *are* the documents themselves). If that's *not* what you meant, then you shouldn't refer to a document as an entry. Also, what I'm saying is that the OP *did* state that he's searching for *words* in a data structure, not for documents. Where those words *came from* is not relevant and the question doesn't even hint that we should focus on it.

Comment: Please read my statements another time. I expect that the given scenario should search documents (from the given datastructure) which contain a certain word (*full text search of one word*). The result of such a search is a set of documents. The other scenario (searching words in a set of words) has no practical business value. The result of such a search is `true` or `false`, it is mostly worthless, so I do strongly suspect that the datastructures entries are not words but documents.

Comment: Let's do this instead: why don't you point out to me which *specific* parts of the OP say, imply, or at least suggest anything about searching documents? The OP only states that there's *some* (i.e. unknown) data structure that needs to be searched. It doesn't even say *what* that DS is. A "document" full of "words" is *not* a data structure. Things such as arrays, binary trees, binary search trees, sets, hash/maps, and so on *are* data structures. Therefore, no matter how "strongly" you may "suspect" anything, you're simply making *unjustified assumptions*.

Comment: I will also add that linking to a page on *search engine indexing* would still not help the OP, since the question *clearly* asked OP for which "**java** feature/library" they'd use. While "search engine indexing" might be a good approach to tackle a specific kind of search problem, is not a relevant topic for OP's question b/c it is not the name of a Java package, interface, or class.

Comment: This is really hairsplitting. I mentioned Lucene, ElasticSarch and SOLR (java frameworks). You did not! And the OP tells us of an interview. My assumptions are just the same as Aarishs. And your assumption is that everything specified in the interview was posted here. Maybe the OP has left out this detail information? So please wait for the OPs feedback for clarification.

Comment: It's not "hairsplitting" to note that you went way off-track and added a lot of (bad) assumptions. It's also not relevant that the other user made the same mistakes. In addition, I *did* ask OP for clarification on those things, 2+ hours ago now; did you not read the comments under OP to see this? When I asked, OP said it had been *"in the written part of the interview"*, that *"nothing ... was ever discussed ... [or] mentioned in the question"*, and that he was given *"no feedback"* beyond being told he had failed. There're no more clarifications for us, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

The hashmap solution is reasonable as stated by others but there are doubts with respect to scalability.

Here is a possible solution for the problem as discussed in the below post

1. Sub-string match If your entry blob is a single sting or word (without any white space) and you need to search arbitrary sub-string within it. In such cases you need to parse every entry to find best possible entries that matches. One uses algorithms like Boyer Moor algorithm. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm) and [this](http://www.inf.fh-flensburg.de/lang/algorithmen/pattern/bmen.htm) for details. This is also equivalent to grep - because grep uses similar stuff inside
2. Indexed search. Here you are assuming that entry contains set of words and search is limited to fixed word lengths. In this case, entries are indexed over all the possible occurrences of words. This is often called "Full Text search". There are number of algorithms to do this and number of open source projects that can be used directly. Many of them, also support wild card search, approximate search etc. as below :
   a. Apache Lucene : http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html
   b. OpenFTS : http://openfts.sourceforge.net/
   c. Sphinx http://sphinxsearch.com/

Most likely if you need "fixed words" as queries, the approach two will be very fast and effective

Reference - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/118759/how-to-quickly-search-through-a-very-large-list-of-strings-records-on-a-databa

Answer (score -2):

Multi-billion entries lie at the edge of what might conceivably be stored in main memory (for instance, storing 10 billion entries at 100 bytes per entry will take 1000 GB main memory).

While storing the data in main memory offers a very high throughput (thousands to millions of requests per second), you'd likely need special hardware (typical blade servers only offers 16 GB, but there are commodity servers that permit installation of up to 3000 GB of main memory). Also, keeping this much data in the Java Heap will likely cause garbage collector pauses of seconds or minutes unless special care is taken.

Therefore, unless the structure of your data admits a very compact representation in main memory (say, you only need membership checking among ints, which is possible with a 512 MB Bitset), you'll not want to store it in main memory, but on disk.

Therefore, you'll need persistence. Any relational or NoSQL database permits efficient searching by key and can handle such amounts of data with ease. To talk to a relational database, use [JPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_API) or [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity). To talk to a non-relational database, you can use their proprietary Java API or an abstraction layer such as [Spring Data](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data/).

You could also implement persistence from scratch if you wanted to (i.e. the interviewer asks for that). A data structure optimized for efficient lookup in external memory is the [B-Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree), that's what many databases use internally :-)

Comment: I don't think this post actually attempts to answer the question. Please make sure the answer is relevant to the actual question: *"So which java feature/library can we use to do the searching in the quickest time possible?"*

Comment: The answer is "any library that talks to a relational or NoSQL database". Would you like me to enumerate them?

Comment: I don't think you need to enumerate them, and I'm not sure that statement saves this post. In addition, just saying that amounts to hand-waving b/c it does not answer much. BTW, I didn't dv. I was actually waiting to see if edits that made this post relevant were made before voting.

Comment: Ok, I mentioned a few libaries, but the key point remains: This was likely a trick question to determine whether OP is aware that heap memory is limited. OP wasn't, and didn't get the job. Perhaps this answer shows him why.

Comment: I'm not really sure how, exactly, this response shows OP what you claim it does.

Comment: Would you like to use an application that needs 100GB RAM and randomly freezes for seconds or minutes? Probably not, right? But that's what happens if you use a `Map` for data sets of such size. I really can't put it any plainer than that. If a particular step in my reasoning is unclear, feel free to tell me which one, but I am not going to write a novel about an insight this basic.